# How to create redirect links with my own url?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a website with Laravel. I will promote some products via affiliation. I have some affiliates links like http://wwww.example.com/aff.php?id=123

I would like to have links like http://www.example.com/go/nameofproduct that redirect to affiliate links

Affiliates links are in a table in my database.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: in this case who controls `www.example.com` ? If it's not you then there's not much you can do about this (other than contact the affiliates to get them to support this for you). If it is you then do share some code of what you've tried so far

Comment: the first www.example.com is my own website. I want url like mywebsite.com/go/affil that redirect to example.com?affil=123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// define the route as you need 'go/{name of the product variable}' 
Route::get('go/{nameOfProduct}','path/ToYourController@goTo');

// method in your controller
function goTo($nameOfProduct) {
 
  // Add some validations for $nameOfProduct and fetch mapped redirect link from your database

  $redirectLink = ' http://wwww.example.com/aff.php?id=123' // fetch from database 

  return redirect()->away($redirectLink);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own route in your website and simply redirect on affiliate url like this:-

```
Route::get('yoururl',function(){
 $link = // fetch link from db
 return redirect($link);
});
```